# How do I change activities using my recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am really confused on how to change activity using a recycler view! Sorry for providing excess code because I have no idea where to write the code or what it even looks like! Any help would be hugely appreciated!
Thanks is advance!

```
public class DazAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DazAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public DazAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current=data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        icon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *how to change activity using a recycler view*?

Comment: @reVerse as in go to switch to a different activity/fragment.

Comment: You should do this via your adapter and an interface. Please edit your question and implement the code for the *DazAdapter*.

Comment: @reVerse sorry about that I had no idea, fixed it there

Answer (score 0):

Try this for quick and dirty:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current=data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
    holder.icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(icon.getContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
             ((Activity) icon.getContext()).startActivity(intent);
       }
    }
}
```

More formally you should create an interface that your `Activity` will implement, then cast the context inside your onclick to this can callback that your view has been clicked, then start the Intent in the activity.

Something like this:

```
public interface OnDazClickListener {
    void onDazClick(String daz);
}

public MyActivity extends Activity implements OnDazClickListener {

    @Override
    onCreate {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        DazAdapter adapter = new DazAdapter(inflater, data, this);
        ...  
    } 

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDazClick(String daz) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }

}

public class DazAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DazAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final OnDazClickListener listener;

    public DazAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<Information> data, OnDazClickListener listener){
      this.inflater = inflater;
      this.data.addAll(data);
      this.listener = listener;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      Information current=data.get(position);
      holder.title.setText(current.title);
      holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
      holder.icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             listener.onDazClick("some information");
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: you wouldn't have a link to a example or tutorial of the more formal method?

Comment: your `onDazClick` `icon` getting error..`cannot resolved symbol `icon``